# How to restrict some commands for admin in Linux(CentOS)

Tags: centos, security, sudo, root, rm

how to restrict some commands for admin in Linux(CentOS)

I tried to use `visudo` in root , and write

`ABC ALL=ALL,!/bin/rm,!/bin/sudo`

to restrict the "ABC" user not to remove some important files.

It worked very well in ABC user ,Linux denied my commands when I type 
`sudo rm -rf /etc/` or remove something important files that need super user.

But there is a problem in script.If I write a script about `sudo rm -rf /etc/`, this script worked and deleted my `/etc/` by using `sudo`to execute.

So `visudo` seemingly can't not work in script.How should I do ?

I need my admin user can use all commands but can't delete my system files.

Comment: You should re-think your approach.  Negative patterns don't work, a user with `sudo` privileges can do things like rename `rm` to something else then `sudo` it, or compile a program that uses `unlink(2)` to do the same thing.  Use `sudo` to state what is allowed, not what is forbidden.

Comment: @SatōKatsura Negative `sudo` patterns do work, just not like OP has in mind. Negative patters in `sudo` are used for exceptions to wildcard rules. The example from the `man sudoers` page: `pete  HPPA = /usr/bin/passwd [A-Za-z]*, !/usr/bin/passwd root` This lets "pete" change the password of anyone except root.

Comment: It's not that they don't _work_, it's that they're quite likely to be totally _ineffective_ as described unless you blacklist each and every _possible_ means to do an end-run.  I can `cp /bin/sh ~/mysh`, run `sudo ~/mysh` since it isn't blacklisted, and now I have a straight-up root shell.

Comment: @DopeGhoti I would do so far as to say negative rules on their own don't work, as in don't achieve any real benefit. Imagine the extreme, that you successfully disable *every* possible means to end. I then put in a disk with a copy of `rm` on it into the machine with a different name, or get it from a website, or using `scp`. What if I write an application that makes unlink system calls? How could you possibly write a negative rule to say: "if a program can remove a file, don't allow it"? I assume `sudo` doesn't interpret system calls of commands that are already started...

Comment: That was rather my point, as I explicitly showed an example for.  I was drawing the distinction between the actual blacklist not _working_ and being an _effective tool_.  They do _work_.  They're just not _useful_ in any practical or effective way.  The only real answer to this in my opinion is "do not put a user into `sudoers` whom you would not trust with unfettered root access to your system without an explicit whitelist of specific commands to run in a privileged environment".

Comment: @DopeGhoti They can be an effective tool is my point, just not on their own. The example from the man sudoers page: `pete HPPA = /usr/bin/passwd [A-Za-z]*, !/usr/bin/passwd root` This lets "pete" change the password of anyone except root. Their purpose is to make wildcard/regex usage more practical, not to stand on their own.

Comment: This: "can use all commands but can't delete my system files" is self-contradicting.

Answer (score 3):

> I need my admin user can use all commands but can't delete my system files.

This is not possible (in particular if you want to protect from some malicious Linux expert), because the root uid 0 has or can get all privileges. However, read also [capabilities(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) (Linux specific).

If you want to simply avoid mistakes, you might use [chattr](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chattr) (for the immutable flag). But a determined admin could still remove such "immutable" files (by first removing the immutable flag).

<sup>(I guess you are mostly concerned by junior admins making trivial mistakes, not by malicious hackers)</sup>

I suggest instead to backup regularly your `/etc/` (perhaps on some remote machine), which is always a good thing to do. And you could also have your own `rm` (as an alias, a function, another executable ....), and decide to version-control `/etc/` (e.g. with [git](http://git-scm.com/), see [etckeeper](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/etckeeper.html))

Read also about [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) executables and [setreuid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setreuid.2.html) (and of course [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)....) system call (this mechanism is the basic brick of protection on Unix, and is used by `sudo` & `su` & `login`).

<sup>BTW, trust is mostly a social issue, and wanting purely technical solutions to social issues is unwise and naive.</sup>

Comment: Rather than something like `chattr` I would recommend a read only filesystem. Again a determined person could remount it, unless you're read-only filesystem was literally read-only media (which would make it a pain to maintain).

Comment: Also, in a sense this wouldn't be the worst way to remind people who essentially have `root` access they shouldn't delete things. Sure they can get around it easily, but it could serve as a reminder they shouldn't. In which case this is similar to just aliasing `rm` to `echo "you shouldn't be deleting things!"` for `root`

Comment: @Centimane: it really depends on the circumstances. I know I like to `chattr +i` my unmounted mount points and ssh/TLS private keys, where a r/o filesystem would be overkill.