# how to restrict users not to login to root by using sudo -i and sudo su - and other if exists

Tags: sudo, su, non-root-user, account-restrictions

I have tried to restrict user by editing `sudoers` file `M ALL=!/bin/su`. I am able to restrict `sudo su -` but not `sudo -i`.

Comment: A few problems with this approach are mentioned here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/392483/how-to-restrict-some-commands-for-admin-in-linuxcentos

Comment: If you're trying to ensure a user can't get a root shell, you need to check that every command you allow users to run via `sudo` doesn't have a way to create a shell.  For example, most editors have a shell escape to allow a user to run a shell.  You also need to make sure any command you do allow users to run via `sudo` doesn't have any holes such as using environment variables controlled by the user.

Comment: I want to allow him in all other activities where as he has to run scripts but not to login as root.

Comment: A seasoned user will know how to get around those limitations easily. They are mere annoyances. I would refine better the security model defining wether certain users need or not to have root access.

Comment: Trivial to get around `ALL=!/bin/su`. See: `sudo su ## Permission denied` but then `ln -s /bin/su /tmp/ouch; sudo /tmp/ouch ## Succeeds`

Comment: Adding to @Andrew’s comment, the limitations he mentions are why you should use `sudoedit` and the various environment-cleaning features of `sudo`.

Answer (score 3):

For your original question, you will need to exclude `/bin/bash` (or whatever is defined as the user's shell in `/etc/passwd`), like so:

```
tomk ALL= ALL,!/bin/su,!/bin/bash
```

**However(!!!)**, as stated already in the comments to your question, even though this will deny the user from running `sudo -s` or `sudo -i`, **it will not really prevent him/her from getting an interactive shell as root.**

From `man sudoers`:

> Limitations of the ‘!’ operator
>
> It is generally not effective to “subtract” commands from ALL using the ‘!’ operator.  A user can trivially circumvent this by copying the desired command to a different name and then executing that.
>        For example:
>
> ```
> bill    ALL = ALL, !SU, !SHELLS
> ```
>
> Doesn't really prevent bill from running the commands listed in SU or SHELLS since he can simply copy those commands to a different name, or use a shell escape from an editor or other program.  There‐
>        fore, these kind of restrictions should be considered advisory at best (and reinforced by policy).
>
> In general, if a user has sudo ALL there is nothing to prevent them from creating their own program that gives them a root shell (or making their own copy of a shell) regardless of any ‘!’ elements in
>        the user specification.

Comment: this worked for me as well thanks @Tom Klino